# Listview controls don't appear in dialog

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

C++ win32 application (not MFC), whose GUI comprises just one dialog box from the resource file [WinMain() calls DialogBox()].  This works fine.

However, adding any "common controls" (listview, tab control, etc) to the dialog and they don't appear when the program is run.  Normal controls (textbox, button, radiobox etc) are displayed, just not listviews or tabs.

The controls are marked as Visible=True in the dialog box editor. Program is linked against comctl32.lib, and even tried putting a copy of comctl32.dll in the same directory as the exe.  Yet these listview and tab controls still don't appear in the dialog box.  What could be causing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling InitCommonControlsEx() in your program?  Required.